# Printing from web on Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, mobile, printing

Alright, so does anyone know of a solution to printing off a android device (not a picture) but a straight from the web without using 3rd party software?

So hypothetically, the user will use a web-based application through and android device.
Once they have completed the questions, they will need that printed.

I know that Android 4.4 Kitkat has this but unfortunately I am not able to get the devices I need with said OS.

Is there any language that can make this possible? 
I have scoured the web and all I have come across are 3rd party apps and articles of 4.4 having this functionality

We have a print button on page and this works on a PC but as soon as it is integrated to a Android it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for anyone that can assist.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=322303 you may eventually get it straight from the browser

Answer (score 0):

I think iOS has a print page feature that uses AirPrint and AirPrint enabled printers.

You can always do `window.print();` in your Javascript.

Comment: The problem is we are using Android Devices... Today I am going to try and figure out how to save a form as a png/jpeg and try and print from device memory instead of through the browser as the tech isn't available without a 3rd party app or 4.4