# Printing from Android

Tags: android, mobile, printing

So I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913331/printing-from-web-on-android) and never got any useful answers so I have tried to change my look on this.

Basically the tech is not available for printing from web on an android device other than a device running 4.4

So my next best solution is to screenshot my users input using an on click function. It then needs to fire another function to print the image from the printer connected to it.

I have though of using a server to do the printing, this would mean I need to install 8+ printers to it and have each tablet print from a specific printer and it seems like a dirty solution.[image]

Above shows a basic network layout of what I am doing. We will be using OTG cables to connect the printers... The problem is the tablets need to be married to one printer and must print from that printer which is also a reason going through the server isn't the greatest of plans.

I also considered converting the input to a canvas and then saving the canvas as an image which is what I think the best solution is.

Any help or suggestions at all would be greatly appreciated and I hope someone has a solution.

PS: I can't use 3rd party apps as the devices will be locked down and users have minimum access and we want this to be automated, not a request that the user must accept first.

EDIT: As pointed out, I failed to ask a direct question, I apologize for this so here it goes.
Google Cloud Printing was an option but was ruled out due to not have internet access in specific areas that it would be deployed in.

My question is if their is a function which could be fired off in order to force the device to print instead of navigating to said image to print it?

Comment: "the tech is not available for printing from web on an android device other than a device running 4.4" -- Google Cloud Print and various vendor-specific solutions work on older versions than this. "We will be using OTG cables to connect the printers" -- only if the printer vendor offers support for that for Android. "I can't use 3rd party apps" -- then you will not be printing anything, as printing bridges are "3rd party apps" even for Android 4.4. Beyond this, Stack Overflow is for programming questions, and you have not asked a question. We cannot give you a "solution" without a question.

Comment: @CommonsWare Without trying to sound rude, It is a "programming question" I just failed to ask it correctly and for this I apologize. I have made an update. I am not from a first world country and internet based solutions are not always available so these would be closed networks with no internet capability.

Comment: Also if you looked at the previous question, I was trying to do this using print from web feature and that is what I meant when I said it can be done from 4.4 etc

Comment: Any Android solution requires "3rd party apps", as they fill the role that print drivers would on a desktop OS. You have indicated that third-party apps are not allowed. If you relax that restriction, your printer manufacturer *might* have an app for pre-4.4 that would allow you to print programmatically. Note that this may still involve user input (e.g., print configuration dialogs), as 4.4's printing does, and I'm unclear whether that is something you can live with or not. And note that all of this will be from Java, not a browser app.

Comment: That is exactly what I thought, I just needed confirmation on it... Thank you so much for your assistance. And Thank you for being clear in your answers as I could understand them perfectly. Have a great day

Comment: You could set up a small server only for printing and have it run a webservice on your local network. The webservice would receive your data, maybe as pdf and then print it. Webservices are android supported and webservice calls can handle up to 2gb of data per call, so you could pass both the desired printer as an argument and the data to the webservice who then handles it accordingly.

Comment: @user3427079 This sounds like an approach I would be looking to take. We have a print server set up but its pushing what we want to be printed that is a pain. Could you give me a push in the right direction about this web service though? I have never done anything like that and it sounds like a good idea.

Comment: I am confused, unless I am missing the question entirely.  Why can't you have a small PHP script on the "server" and fire it from the Android device.  Simply have the Android device access http://server/printscript.php and add a screenshot as a parameter.

Comment: @Morantis Well think of it this way. We have a set of parameters that need to be printed, not the entire page so a screenshot would only suffice if we made an entire page of what we need printed... We have gone with a different approach and have since gone to Win8 tablets in order to work around the headache that is Silent Android Printing...

Comment: Ok that works too.  Keep in mind that you can pass anything you want to a PHP script.  It could be as such server/printscript.php#HELLOWORLD and then the script can pull that data and print HELLOWORLD or whatever and you can construct that URL inside of Android but glad you got it working.

Comment: @morantis thank you and I will definitely look into it in case it is ever needed in the future

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @user3427079 you could set up a print server and reroute the print operation through it.
If the page you want to print is static or depends only by data that you can forward to the print server, then you could simply push its url and those data to the print server and let it do the rest.
If the page changes its aspect on the client side based on the user input or the user session data, then you are forced to send a static view of the page to the print server; you can use the [WebView.capturePicture()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#capturePicture()) method to get the page as an image.
In any case the print request should be a simple HTTP post containing the print information, i.e. what to print (the url of the page or the image as an attachment) and where to print (which printer).
If you have sent to the print server the page url, the server should render the page in an embedded browser and issue a print command.
If you have sent the page as an image then the server should only print it.